# Windows lockscreen shows image but no information

Tags: windows-11, lock-screen

I am aware that this question has been asked before, but the relevant questions are two or more years old. I have tried all those 'solutions' to no avail.
I am seeing the Lockscreen image, but NOT the information about where the image was taken, nor the option to 'like' the image. Additionally the image is only changing about once a week. It's been like this for several months. Prior to this I DID see the information, and the image changed every couple of days. I suspect it was a Windows Update that caused this change, but I'm not sure.

Personalization is set to 'Windows Lockscreen
Country or Region is set to 'United Kingdom'.

This seems to be quite a common problem. I am wondering if there are any new solutions? Maybe Microsoft have done something about it?

Comment: Are you part of a domain?  As in .. controlled by your company?  In prior jobs, I have had home machines (not part of the domain) show the info and work machines (part of the domain) and thus members of the domain's group policy that did not.

Comment: No, utterly independent. Home office desktop computer.

Comment: Bummer dude.  One thing about this site.. `I have tried all those 'solutions' to no avail. ` is not helpful.. How are we supposed to know what you have or haven't tried?  Clearly, if there is a solution that works that you haven't found, there is no way for any of us to know.  Are we supposed to guess?  A better question gets a faster solution (if one it there to be found).  I too had this problem, but mine was because of a group policy on a domain.

Comment: Fair comment. I willl prepare a list and edit my original post accordingly.